# Shapes must be equal rank, but are 0 and 2 From merging shape 0 with other shapes. for '{{node AddN}} = AddN[N=2, T=DT_FLOAT] bug?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am currently trying to train an EEGnet model with tensorflow to do binary classification of EEG signals (paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.08024. My model is as follows:

```
    fs = 512        # sampling frequency  
    def EEGNet_Classifier_new(nb_classes, Chans = 160, Samples = 1588, regRate = 0.0001,
           dropoutRate = 0.25, kernLength = fs//2, numFilters = 8, numSpatialFliters=1):
        batch_size = 32  

        #input1 = tf.keras.layers.Input(batch_shape=(batch_size, 1, Chans, Samples))
        input1 = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=( 1,Chans, Samples))

        layer1=tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(numFilters, (1, kernLength), strides=(1, 1), padding='same',
                             activation=None, use_bias=True,
                             kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.GlorotUniform(),
                             name='conv2d_1')(input1)

        layer1=tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(axis=-1,  name='bn_1')(layer1)          
        layer1 = tf.keras.layers.DepthwiseConv2D(kernel_size=(1, kernLength),strides=(1, 1),padding='same', name='depthwise_conv2d_1') (layer1)

        layer1= tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(axis=-1,  name='bn_2')(layer1)
        layer1= tf.keras.layers.Activation('elu')(layer1)
    
        layer1= tf.keras.layers.AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(1, 4), strides=(1, 4), name='ave_pooling')(layer1)     

        layer1 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=dropoutRate, name='dropout_1')(layer1) 

  
        layer2 = tf.keras.layers.SeparableConv2D(filters=numFilters, kernel_size=(1, 16), strides(1, 1), padding='same',depth_multiplier=1, activation=None, use_bias=False,                                              
    depthwise_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.GlorotUniform(),                                         
    pointwise_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.GlorotUniform(),name='separable_conv2d')(layer1)
        layer2 = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(axis=-1, name='bn_3')(layer2)
        layer2 = tf.keras.layers.Activation('elu')(layer2)
        layer2 = tf.keras.layers.AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(1, 8), strides=(1, 8), name='ave_pooling2')(layer2)
        layer2 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=dropoutRate, name='dropout_2')(layer2)  
        flatten= tf.keras.layers.Flatten(name = 'flatten')(layer2)
        print(flatten.shape)
        output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(nb_classes, activation="sigmoid",                           
        kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.constraints.max_norm(max_value=0.25,axis=1),
                            name='fc_output')(flatten)    
        print(output.shape)``
   #.   softmax = tf.keras.layers.Activation('sigmoid', name='sigmoid')(output)
    
        return tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=input1, outputs=output)

    model = EEGNet_Classifier_new(nb_classes=2, Chans=160, Samples=1588, regRate=0.0001)
    model.summary()
    model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001),            loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

    Ytrain1 = np.expand_dims(Ytrain1, axis=1)

    x_train, x_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(XX, Ytrain1, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
    y_train = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes=2)
    y_val = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_val, num_classes=2)

    print(x_train.shape)
    print(y_train.shape)
    print(x_val.shape)
    print(y_val.shape)

    model =EEGNet_Classifier_new(nb_classes=2, Chans = 160, Samples = 1588, regRate = 0.0001,)
    model.summary()
    print(model.layers)
    model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001),    loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

    model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=100, validation_data=(x_val, y_val))
```

the shape of my different dataset are

```
train =(480, 1, 160, 1588)
ytrain=(480, 2)
xval=(120, 1, 160, 1588)
yval=(120, 2)
```

As soon as I start the training. It blocks at the first time and sends me back the following message. I've tried to display my logs during the training phase, but it doesn't work, because the function stops at the first step.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/djeserkordon/Desktop/test biosemite/EEGNE.py", line 334, in <module>
    model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=100, batch_size=None, validation_data=(x_val, y_val),callbacks=[error_callback])
  File "/Users/djeserkordon/miniconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "/var/folders/xz/vzw73_1x4qd8h6_bhryn95mh0000gn/T/__autograph_generated_file9xvk4qlk.py", line 15, in tf__train_function
    retval_ = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(step_function), (ag__.ld(self), ag__.ld(iterator)), None, fscope)
ValueError: in user code:

    File "/Users/djeserkordon/miniconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1249, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/Users/djeserkordon/miniconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1233, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/Users/djeserkordon/miniconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1222, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/Users/djeserkordon/miniconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1024, in train_step
        loss = self.compute_loss(x, y, y_pred, sample_weight)
    File "/Users/djeserkordon/miniconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1082, in compute_loss
        return self.compiled_loss(
    File "/Users/djeserkordon/miniconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/engine/compile_utils.py", line 316, in __call__
        total_total_loss_mean_value = tf.add_n(total_loss_mean_values)

    ValueError: Shapes must be equal rank, but are 0 and 2
        From merging shape 0 with other shapes. for '{{node AddN}} = AddN[N=2, T=DT_FLOAT](binary_crossentropy/weighted_loss/value, fc_output/kernel/Regularizer/mul)' with input shapes: [], [40,2].
```

I run python on a macbook pro M1 with a conda python 3.10 environment created especially for this model.

the aim will obviously be to run it on gpus with a larger learning base. I'm just trying to get my code to work locally for a start.